# How to get a child class value in Javascript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hope to get the value (such as: 2017-03-03 10:41) of the class "fileDate" when I click the button 'CssDetails', but the following code can't return correct result, how can I write a jQuery code? Thanks!

**Js File**

```
 $('.CssDetails').click(function () {
      var fileDate=  $(this).parent().siblings("class='middleli']").childs("class='fileDate']").val();
      alert(fileDate);  
  });
```

**Html Code**

```
   <ul class="ul-file">
            <section class="files">
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" />
                        <span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightli">
                       <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
                       <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
                       <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middleli">
                        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
                        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A2.PNG</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightli">
                         <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span><span class="CssDetails">Details</span><span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middleli">
                         <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
                         <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </section>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In order to get children of a node you can use
>   `$('Selector').find('Selector')` method

If i understand you correctly this will solve your problem

Following are the issues in your code :-

1. In order to find class you can use `.` in front of class no need to use `$('class[class-name]')`
2. In order to get children of a node you can use `$('Selector').find('Selector')` method
3. In order to get content inside a div you can use `text()` method

```js
$('.CssDetails').click(function() {
  var fileDate = $(this).parent().siblings(".middleli").find(".fileDate").text();
  alert(fileDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-file">
  <section class="files">
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
      <div class="leftli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" />
        <span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span>
      </div>
      <div class="rightli">
        <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
        <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
        <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
      </div>
      <div class="middleli">
        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
      <div class="leftli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A2.PNG</span>
      </div>
      <div class="rightli">
        <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span><span class="CssDetails">Details</span><span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
      </div>
      <div class="middleli">
        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:43</span>
        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </section>
</ul>
```

Comment: @HelloCW i didn't get you

Comment: @HelloCW it is alerting correctly i think can you pls elaborate what you r seeing wrong you can run this code here by clicking `Run code snippet `button

Comment: Thanks!  I hope to get the valuse such as  2017-03-03 10:41 , but your code result blank

Comment: No you will getting an alert with Date value when clicking on `Details` after running my answer by clicking `Run code snippet` button

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('.CssDetails').click(function() {
  var fileDate = $(this).closest('.rightli').next('.middleli').find(".fileDate").text();
  alert(fileDate);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-file">
  <section class="files">
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
      <div class="leftli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" />
        <span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span>
      </div>
      <div class="rightli">
        <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
        <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
        <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
      </div>
      <div class="middleli">
        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
      <div class="leftli">
        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A2.PNG</span>
      </div>
      <div class="rightli">
        <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span><span class="CssDetails">Details</span><span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
      </div>
      <div class="middleli">
        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
      </div>
    </li>
  </section>
</ul>
```

1. use `.text()` instead of `.val()`
2. Also in selector use closest() to get the parent `.rightli` which is the sibling of `.middleli` which is the parent of `fileDate` where you can use `.find()`

Comment: Ninja'd me @guardio

Answer (score 1):

Make use of `closest` and `find`. Also `li` elements don't have a `val()` property but `text()` property

```js
$('.CssDetails').click(function () {
      var fileDate=  $(this).closest('.rightli').next('.middleli').find('.fileDate').text();
      alert(fileDate);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-file">
            <section class="files">
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" />
                        <span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightli">
                       <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
                       <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
                       <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middleli">
                        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
                        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A2.PNG</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightli">
                         <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span><span class="CssDetails">Details</span><span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middleli">
                         <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
                         <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </section>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the selector. Try the following:

```js
$('.CssDetails').click(function () {
      var fileDate=  $(this).parent().siblings('div.middleli').find('span.fileDate').text();
      console.log(fileDate);  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="ul-file">
            <section class="files">
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A1.PNG" />
                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" />
                        <span class="CssHandleKnown">A1.PNG</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightli">
                       <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span>
                       <span class="CssDetails">Details</span>
                       <span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middleli">
                        <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
                        <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <input type="hidden" value="/storage/emulated/0/Pictures/A2.PNG" />
                    <div class="leftli">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="CHFile" class="FilenameCheckboxForSelect" /><span class="CssHandleKnown">A2.PNG</span> 
                    </div>
                    <div class="rightli">
                         <span class="CssCopy">Copy</span><span class="CssDetails">Details</span><span class="CssDownloadSingle">Download</span><span class="CssRename">Rename</span><span class="CssDeleteSingle">Delete</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="middleli">
                         <span class="fileDate">2017-03-03 10:41</span>
                         <span class="filesize">66 KB</span>
                    </div>
                </li>
            </section>
        </ul>
```